# How can i Dynamically Update the React Helmet Value when state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-helmet

I want to dynamically update the React Helmet value, I tried it with the state but whenever I am changing pages It won't update, the value instead it's showing the older value
I want to add a meta tag for SEO the canonical tag and every page changes I want to update it but when I am reloading the page it is updating but not on the page changes with React Router

```
function App() {
 
  const location = useLocation();
  const [canonical, setCanonical] = useState(window.location.href);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCanonical(window.location.href);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet>
       
        <link rel="canonical" href={canonical} />
      </Helmet>
  

I tried with the following code present in my App.js file  I want to update it the canonical value when the state changes
```

Answer (score 0):

try `useLocation` hook to detect route changes

```
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Location changed');
}, [location]);
```

Comment: const location = useLocation();
  const [canonical, setCanonical] = useState(window.location.href);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    setCanonical(window.location.href);
  }, [location]);

I am using it like this and its throwing error 

Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

Comment: where do you define `Router`

Comment: Please check the question I used it like this, I edited the question with whole file

Comment: useLocation can be used inside `Router` level. you need to move  `link` component inside the `browser` route and move useLocation inside a subcomponent within the `app` component